# List or dictionary in C#

Tags: c#

I need two lists as output, one of which is a list of index and the other is of the corresponding value till the condition is satisfied..

```
//initializing the first value of TotalDebts
double TotalDebts = 30000;
for (int i = 0; i < 250; i++)
{
    if (TotalDebts > 0)
    {
        double DebtsLessIncome = Convert.ToDouble(TotalDebts - 1000);
        double InterestCharged = Convert.ToDouble((DebtsLessIncome * 5) / 100);
        double InterestDebt = Convert.ToDouble(DebtsLessIncome + InterestCharged);
        double InterestDebtMLE = Convert.ToDouble(InterestDebt + 500);
        double TotalDebts = Convert.ToDouble(InterestDebtMLE);
        //how to add TotalDebts in list or dictionary from each loop as index 0,1,2 and so on 
        List<double> AllDebits = new List<double>();
        AllDebits.Add(TotalDebts);
        // how to retrieve each index and value and store index in one list and value in second list
    }
}
```

Comment: You are redeclaring AllDebits inside a loop, so it will get wiped out each time. Move it outside of the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a list of tuples like this:

```
double TotalDebts = 30000;
list<Tuple<int, double>> AllDebits = new list<Tuple<int, double>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 250; i++)
{
    if (TotalDebts > 0)
    {
        double DebtsLessIncome = Convert.ToDouble(TotalDebts - 1000);
        double InterestCharged = Convert.ToDouble((DebtsLessIncome * 5) / 100);
        double InterestDebt = Convert.ToDouble(DebtsLessIncome + InterestCharged);
        double InterestDebtMLE = Convert.ToDouble(InterestDebt + 500);
        TotalDebts = Convert.ToDouble(InterestDebtMLE);
        AllDebits.Add(new Tuple<int,double>(i, TotalDebts));
    }
}
```

It really depends on what you'll be using this for. If the data is really just to display in a list then this is fine. However, if the index is to be used for something else (id perhaps?) then a Dictionary (as per fubo's answer) would be much better, as the index has meaning and needs to be unique (Dictionaries don't allow duplicate keys).

Answer (score 5):

Based on "how to retrieve each index and value" - I assume you want to access the data by index (=year?) - dictionary works fine for that.

```
double TotalDebts = 30000;
Dictionary<int, double> dResult = new Dictionary<int, double>();
for (int i = 0; i < 250; i++)
{
    if (TotalDebts > 0)
    {
        double DebtsLessIncome = Convert.ToDouble(TotalDebts - 1000);
        double InterestCharged = Convert.ToDouble((DebtsLessIncome * 5) / 100);
        double InterestDebt = Convert.ToDouble(DebtsLessIncome + InterestCharged);
        double InterestDebtMLE = Convert.ToDouble(InterestDebt + 500);
        TotalDebts = Convert.ToDouble(InterestDebtMLE);
        dResult.Add(i, TotalDebts);
    }
}
```

Notes

- `Dictionary` does not support ordered iteration so if you need to output list of year/debt pairs use some other data structure (i.e. `List<KeyValuePair<int, decimal>>`).
- usually one would use `decimal` for money values instead of `float`/`double`.

**Update** (split dictionary into 2 lists)

```
List<int> lIndex = dResult.Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
List<double> lDepts = dResult.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: BTW, consider removing that extra `Convert.ToDouble` from code.

Comment: @PrakashKandel - if you need separate lists then create them from the Dictionary like this: List<int> indexes = AllDebits.Select(x => x.Key).ToList(); For the debits just switch 'x.Key' to 'x.Value' and make the list of type double (or decimal if you have switched to that).